# Is creating a non-rectangular keyboard possible?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to create a custom Android keyboard that is in a arc like shape, but I don't know if it is at all possible or how to do it. So I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible to create a non-rectangular keyboard. Check the android [softkeyboard](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=tree) implementation and change the layouts to what you want. AFAIK, its using a custom view which handles the buttons addition/removal, you need to change this to achieve this.

Comment: Would I have to change the KeyboardRow class that's defined in the keyboard? I think I would, given what I'm trying to do, but I just want to be absolutely sure